# reg query remote computer not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, registry

I have the following problem. At work I'm working on a domain and i'm writing a batch script that, among other things, queries remotely windows registry from other machines in the domain. There, things work ok. That is, a query like:

```
reg query \\MACHINE1\HKLM\SYSTEM
```

works just fine. However while doing some testing at home I just can't access windows registry in computer A from computer B. The same command
in my small 2 PC network result in:

```
ERROR: Cannot find network path
```

Or something similar, not sure how to translate it from Spanish: *ERROR: No se ha encontrado la ruta de acceso a la red.* One machine is running Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bits, the other Windows 7 Pro 64-bits. They can ping each other. They both have shared folders and when clicking on Network icon both machines show up, as well as the shared resources.

What am i missing???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Try adding TCP port 139](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772831%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to your Windows Firewall exceptions list on the computer whose registry will be queried remotely.

Comment: Hi rojo. Firewall is turned off :(

Comment: Is the Remote Registry Service running on the remote machine?

Comment: Hi Eduardo, Remote Registry Service is running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this as a local admin on  the machine being read. See `runas` command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is preventing you from running `reg query` against remote machines, but I do have a potential workaround to suggest until you figure out what sort of security restriction is blocking you.  You can invoke the WMI [StdRegProv class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via `wmic`.  It's a little tricky, and I don't even remember where I first learned about this functionality, but it is useful where remote registry calls are directly blocked but WMI remote procedure calls are not.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "remotePC=machine1"
set "remoteUser=username or domain\username"
set "remotePass=password"

set "HKCR=&H80000000"
set "HKLM=&H80000002"
set "HKU=&H80000003"
set "HKCC=&H80000005"

set "wmic=wmic /node:%remotePC% /user:%remoteUser% /password:%remotePass%"

rem // to enumerate keys in \\HKLM\SYSTEM, do:
%wmic% class stdregprov call EnumKey hDefKey="%HKLM%" sSubKeyName="SYSTEM"

rem // to enumerate values in \\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, do:
%wmic% class stdregprov call EnumValues hDefKey="%HKLM%" sSubKeyName="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"

rem // note the double backslashes in sSubKeyName above
```

Besides `EnumKey` and `EnumValues`, there are more methods you can call -- `GetDWORDValue`, `GetExpandedStringValue`, `DeleteKey`, and many others.  [See the MSDN StdRegProv class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fixed the problem. As I mentioned problem was with a small 2 PC home network used for testing (configured as Workgroup, Windows 7 64 bits and
Windows 8.1 32 bits). Here is what I did:

1. Enable Administrator account on both PCs and set them with same pwd.
2. Then, accessed a shared resource of say computer A from computer B. While
   at computer B computer A asks for user name and pwd. I entered it and   ask the system to save it. Repeat the same operation but in the opposite
   direction.

Now I can reg query, add or delete from A to B and from B to A.

Thanks for your answers. Happy Holidays!